# how to know the client being disconnected from the server when using node.js websocket library ws

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am working the web socket with node.js, the code works in half that it can create connection and receive messages,

```
var { WebSocketServer, WebSocket } = require('ws')
const ws_server = new WebSocketServer({   port: 8080    });

ws_server.on('connection', (ws) => {
    ws.on("message", function(msg,isBinary) { 
        console.log('on message',msg.toString()); 
    })
    // something wrong, client is not defined
    ws.on('close', (client) => console.log('Client has disconnected!'),client);  
});
```

however when the client closes the connection, I want to know what client is disconnected.

ws.on('close', (client) => console.log('Client has disconnected!'),client);

this code above gives me an error that client is not defined, so my question is how to know the client information - client id when the client is disconnected from the server.

Comment: You don't even show what you expect `client` to be.  If you want to know which webSocket disconnected, that is available as the variable `ws` in the closure where you close event handler is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ws` client, which you have in connection callback is `Object` to which you can add any property you want and it is kept all the time the connection is alive, and also on close.

So add any property that will help you identify your client and use it in the client's `on close` callback.

```
const wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080})
wss.on('connection', (ws) => 
    { ws.user = CLIENT_NAME; 
      console.log('CLIENT CONNECTION ESTABLISHED', ws.user); 
      ws.on('close', (code, data) => {
        console.log('CLIENT DISCONNECTED: ', ws.user))
      }
    }
)
```

Through the time you will maybe need authenticate the connected client, so follow [these instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#client-authentication). They will help you better identify the incoming client connection.